# Tiki torch along property line

Tags: united-states, property

If I have a tiki torch placed vertically on my property next to the pole there on my neighbor's property, and it catches fire, am I legally responsible?

[image]

Comment: In what country?

Comment: @RonBeyer United States

Comment: Your Tiki torch may be vertical, but your photo is horizontal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may depend on the jurisdiction (although I  can't readily think of one where this is not the case) but deliberately, recklessly or negligently putting a burning object next to someone else's property knowing that there is a real risk of it catching fire (and going ahead with it anyway) will almost definitely make one liable: especially if there is an [ulterior motive](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/71052/problem-with-neighbors).

In [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) This would be called arson - causing criminal damage by fire - an offence contrary to [section 1(3) of the Criminal Damage Act 1971](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1971/48/section/1?timeline=false)

<sub>Cross posted with the jurisdiction defining comment</sub>